# ComboBox & ListBox are not displaying contents of text file

Tags: c#, windows

I have an assignment to create an order form for an icecream shop, and in order to put toppings and flavors into the list and combo box, I need to read it from a text file. I followed the instructions and really bad video tutorial and I have my text files in my bin/debug folder with the respective flavors and toppings on the files. It runs fine except for that the drop down list is blank and so is the list box. This is C# and I am using a windows form app. Here is my code

```
namespace Lab5_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            saveButton.Text = "&Save";
            exitButton.Text = "&Exit";

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateBoxes();

            flavorsComboBox.SelectedItem = "Vanilla";
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // writes order information to output file
                StreamWriter outputFile;
                outputFile = File.AppendText("Orders.txt");

                outputFile.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy"));

                if (sugarConeRadioButton.Checked)
                {
                    outputFile.WriteLine("Sugar Cone");
                }
                else
                {
                    outputFile.WriteLine("Waffle Cone");
                }

                outputFile.WriteLine(flavorsComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());

                for (int count = 0; count < toppingsListBox.Items.Count; count++)
                {
                    if (toppingsListBox.GetSelected(count))
                    {
                        outputFile.WriteLine(toppingsListBox.Items[count]);
                    }
                }

                outputFile.WriteLine();
                outputFile.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            sugarConeRadioButton.Checked = true;
            flavorsComboBox.SelectedItem = "Vanilla";
            toppingsListBox.ClearSelected();
            sugarConeRadioButton.Focus();

        }

        private void PopulateBoxes()
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader inputFile;

                inputFile = File.OpenText("Flavors.txt");
                while (inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    flavorsComboBox.Items.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
                }
                inputFile.Close();

                inputFile = File.OpenText("Toppings.txt");
                while (inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    toppingsListBox.Items.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
                }
                inputFile.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                this.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to [debug your code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx). `while (inputFile.EndOfStream) {}` probably doesnt do what you think it does.

Comment: Both of your `while` loops in `PopulateBoxes` have the same problem. Use the debugger to step through the code to see if you can figure out why. (If you just read the code very carefully and think about what it's doing, you can probably figure it out without even needing the debugger.)

Comment: Put your two text files in your project source folder. That way you can edit them like any other file. Right click each file and choose properties. _(from memory, on a phone)_ set the file type property to _Content_ and the copy property to _Copy Always_. Now, when you compile your code, the files will get copied to the output folder for your project (where the EXE resides)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking others to debug your code is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

File IO life is easier, if you want the entire file contents on a line by line basis, if you use the System.IO.File.ReadAllLines helper

For example

```
    private void PopulateBoxes()
    {
        try
        {
            flavorsComboBox.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines("Flavors.txt").ToList();

            toppingsListBox.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines("Toppings.txt").ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Or

```
    private void PopulateBoxes()
    {
        try
        {
            flavorsComboBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("Flavors.txt"));

            toppingsListBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("Toppings.txt"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```